# Do updates overwrite changes to /etc/default/grub?

Tags: grub2, updates, configuration

When rebooting (18.04), my screen stayed black until the actual login appeared.

It seems that the:

> GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

line in `/etc/default/grub` had reverted back to being a commented-out line.

The file was dated August 4 at 8:11:32, which according to `/varlog/dpkg/log` is when a software update occurred:

```
…
2020-08-04 08:11:32 configure ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:18.04.38 <none>
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status unpacked ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:18.04.38
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status half-configured ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:18.04.38
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status installed ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:18.04.38
2020-08-04 08:11:32 configure grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17 <none>
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status unpacked grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status unpacked grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status unpacked grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:32 status half-configured grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:34 status installed grub-pc:amd64 2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:34 configure grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17 <none>
2020-08-04 08:11:34 status unpacked grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:34 status half-configured grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:35 status installed grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64 1.93.19+2.02-2ubuntu8.17
2020-08-04 08:11:35 trigproc systemd:amd64 237-3ubuntu10.41 <none>
…
```

It doesn't make sense that an update would overwrite this file, which is intended to contain locally edited configuration.

Was that a one time mistake, or is there something I'm supposed to do to prevent this from happening again, or what?

Comment: As far as I know, any mkcofig type of script will that wants to make a change will ASK YOU beforehand, referring to the current grub.config as "currently has been locally modified" or some such. So if that happened you might remember. So reset that line, save it, remember to run grub-update afterwards and then let us all know if it happens again.

Comment: A full reinstall of grub will overwrite the configuration files. I backup my 40_custom and have a script to edit my /etc/default/grub with the changes I want. Any configuration file in /etc that you manually edit should be backed up. I only edit a few, so copy those into /home so my regular backup of /home includes those.